# Jquery change animation effect under 767

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make an animation effect change under 767 screen width?
I have a div what contains some regional information, but it is not fit under 767. I changed the absolute div to relative with css. It works good, but looks ugly with the fadein effect. I'd like to change it to SlideDown.

Is there any good solution for this?

Thanks all help!

Here is my code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $('#regio-settings').click(function() {
            $('#regiobox').slideDown(300, "linear");
            return false;
        });
        $('#regiobox-close').click(function() {
            $('#regiobox').slideUp(300, "linear");
            return false;
        });


    } else {
         $('#regio-settings').click(function() {
            $('#regiobox').fadeIn(300, "linear");
            return false;
        });
        $('#regiobox-close').click(function() {
            $('#regiobox').fadeOut(300, "linear");
            return false;
        });
    }



    });
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use css for the effect(http://davidwalsh.name/css-slide), with jquery just change the class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

- You don't need the `resize` handler
- never bind events within a `resize` handler as they'd **uselessly** bind the event too many times as and when you resize the window
- Have a function that'd return a flag based on the screen size
- Based on the flag apply appropriate animations.

Here is an example to demonstrate the above.

```js
//Returns whether or not the screen is < 767
function isNarrowScreen() {
    return $(window).width() < 767;
}

$('#regio-settings').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Assigns slideDown or fadeIn based on the screen width
    var anim = isNarrowScreen() && "slideDown" || "fadeIn";
    //Apply either slideDown or fadeIn
    $('#regiobox')[anim](300, "linear");
});

$('#regiobox-close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Assigns slideUp or fadeOut based on the screen width
    var anim = isNarrowScreen() && "slideUp" || "fadeOut";
    //Apply either slideUp or fadeOut
    $('#regiobox')[anim](300, "linear");
});
```

```css
#regiobox {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regiobox"></div>

<button id="regio-settings">Open</button>
<button id="regiobox-close">Close</button>
```

Hope that helps.